mongoDB Query Unwind issue
I have a mongoDB Query that uses aggregation. I am applying projection and then unwind.
 ProjectionOperation projectionPreUnwind = Aggregation.project(Fields.from(Fields.field("result.detections.reference.control", "result.detections.reference.control")));

        UnwindOperation unwindOpn = Aggregation.unwind("result.detections");

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(projectionPreUnwind, unwindOpn);

        LOGGER.info(" aggregation {}", aggregation);

        AggregationResults<String> detectionsDataAggr = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, CASES_COLLECTION, String.class);

The code result in Error
2024-10-23 16:48:00.097  INFO B33543D --- [nio-8082-exec-9] .c.c.s.d.r.c.i.MyRepoImpl : ENTERING   aggregation [!!!org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation@3fee8ffe=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Invalid reference 'result.detections'!!!!]

2024-10-23 16:48:03.158 ERROR B33543D --- [nio-8082-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference 'result.detections'!] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference 'result.detections'!
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:114)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:77)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.UnwindOperation.toDocument(UnwindOperation.java:95)
Sample JSON File
{
"result": {
    "aiModel": "",
    "detections": [
        {
            "aiStatus": "PASS",
            "reference": {
                "attribute": "TEST",
                "control": "C Test"
            }
        },
        {
            "aiStatus": "FAIL",
            "reference": {
                "attribute": "TES22T",
                "control": "C Test"
            }
        }
    ]
}

}

Not familiar with Java's MongoDB library. Did you forget a $ sign for "result.detections" → "$result.detections"?

"$result.detections"  shows same error  "Invalid reference 'result.detections'!!!!"

The java code produces query that run fine on mongoConsole. But when i try Aggregation.unwind("result.detections"); then it result in error  "Invalid reference 'result.detections'!!!!"    ====> generated query without unwind      {
$project: {
"result.detections.reference.attribute": 1,
"result.detections.reference.control": 1
}
}

I think the problem is in ProjectOperation
You are trying with same key and try to access value with same key and then you are trying to unwind that but its throw error because in unwind operation you can get proper reference of a key so review below code and give simple key in projection.
I think you can try projection like this
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project().and("YOUR_ACTUAL_FIELD_WHICH_ONLY_YOU_WANT").as("KEY_WHICH_YOU_DEFINE_TO_YOUR_VALUE");

Then you should try unwind operation
UnwindOperation unwindOpn = Aggregation.unwind("YOUR_PROJECTION_OUTPUT_KEY");

I am also attaching the correct mongo query :
https://mongoplayground.net/p/IPPFG-gr3uY
Hope this will work for you.

//    Using projection with this code, solved the issue.

Document projectFields = new Document();
 projectFields.append("_id", 1);
 projectFields.append("result.detections.reference.control", 1);
 
 AggregationOperation projectionPreUnwind = context -> new Document("$project", projectFields);

